# GoLang XML marshalling customization (marshal without root element)

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

How to marshal without root element?

```
type Ids struct {
  Id []string `xml:"id"`
}

IdsStr, _ := xml.Marshal(&Ids{[]string{"test1", "test2"}})
```

Output IdsStr is:

```
<Ids><id>test1</id><id>test2</id></Ids>
```

It should be without Ids element:

```
<id>test1</id><id>test2</id>
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ao_k2WZNY-g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...But how can I set voluntary xml names for elements? Vals []id xml:"idSomeOther" returns id after xml marshaled because it's name of type... I need to customize type id to type IdXml but xml marshaled should return id. How can I get it?

You can use `XMLName xml.Name`, tag `xml:",chardata"` (etc.) to customize a `struct`

```
type Customs struct {
    Vals []CustomXml
}

type CustomXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Chardata string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    customs := Customs{
        []CustomXml{
            {XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "1"}, Chardata: "XXX"},
            {XMLName: xml.Name{Local: "2"}, Chardata: "YYY"}},
    }
    res, _ := xml.Marshal(customs.Vals)
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```

*0utput*

```
<1>XXX</1><2>YYY</2>
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vNP_2UbIn2w)

also, look at on [src/encoding/xml/](https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/) to find examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
type id string 

func main() {
    IdsStr, _ := xml.Marshal([]id{"test1", "test2"})
    fmt.Println(string(IdsStr))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DlFqWJLZRr9)

or

```
type id string

type Ids struct {
    Vals []id 
}

func main() {
    ids := &Ids{[]id{"test1", "test2"}}
    IdsStr, _ := xml.Marshal(ids.Vals)
    fmt.Println(string(IdsStr))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Tu3oJ9TyVyL)

*0utput*

```
<id>test1</id><id>test2</id>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I set voluntary xml names for elements? Vals []id xml:"idSomeOther" returns id after xml marshaled because it's name of type... I need to customize type id to type IdXml but xml marshaled should return id. How can I get it?
https://play.golang.org/p/DtEPBc_M3LK